# Typing special characters with keyboard shortcuts instead of alt-numbers on Windows

Tags: windows, characters, keyboard-shortcuts, special-characters

How can I type special characters with keyboard shortcuts, like on OSX?

For example Option+Shift+R will make an ‰ (per mil-symbol) on Mac, how do I do the same on Windows?

I have already tried the application WizKey but it didn't work like I wanted. It doesn't allow me to bind Ctrl and a symbol, ex. "-", to write out a character. WizKey had too little options overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would be to create a keyboard layout from scratch, using the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx).

You can load an existing layout and customize it however you want, or create a brand new one, including combinations with modifier keys.