# VMWare Windows on OSX : keyboard missing keys

Tags: keyboard, vmware-fusion

Im running Windows 7 on OSX Yosemite with VMWare Fusion 7. Some keys were missing so following [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/600043/typing-special-characters-with-keyboard-shortcuts-instead-of-alt-numbers-on-wind) I use a virtual keyboard manager and it works (Alt Shift L -> "|" for instance)

However, I can't map the '<' key on my keyboard with this tool : it shows up on the virtual keyboard but doesn't work. I configured this key the same way as I configured other vanilla keys ; it worked for vanilla keys (e.g replacing 'a' with 'b') but not for this one.

Any idea why ? NB : Im using a French Mac keyboard. I have tried with the 3 VMWare settings keyboard profiles (Default, Mac, Windows)

[image]

Comment: on an international English keyboard PC or Mac, it would be shift/comma [positioned just right of m]

Comment: Thanks, I found the sign just above the Tab key. However I am asking how to map it to the key that I use (see screenshot)